# Call ink contract using rust

Tags: ink, rust, substrate-contracts-node, subxt

I'm a developer who wants to call the ink contract's function from the outside. I already know that ink contract supports cross-contract. But what I want to do is call the function using subxt or node_runtime crate or etc. I don't want to use polkadot js, but want to implement all features in rust and test it. **(rust version of web3.js and polkadot.js)**

I tried to implement this by using this function: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/testing/integration-tests/src/frame/contracts.rs#L136 but I don't know how to use this function in testnet(rococo or Shibuya) or my local node.

And I also tried to use node_runtime and many other things, but I couldn't make it.

Thank you for any support.

Answer (score 4):

With Rust, it's a bit more complicated than with JS/TS.

Here's an example of how to call a contract using `subxt`:

```rust
// assuming you have `api` and the contract address
let mut call_data = Vec::<u8>::new();
        //append the selector
call_data.append(&mut (&blake2_256("method_name".as_bytes())[0..4]).to_vec());
        //append the arguments
call_data.append(&mut scale::Encode::encode(&(
            AccountId32::from_string(&arg1).ok()?,
            arg2,
            arg3,
        )));
api.tx().contracts().call(
            AccountId32::from_string(contract).ok()?.into(), // contract address
            0, // transferred_value
            20_000_000_000, // gas limit
            None, // storage deposit limit
            call_data, // the call data
        ))
        .sign_and_submit(&signer) // your signer object
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! 

But set `api` is what I don't know. How do you set `api` for this? 

```let api = OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::new().await?;```

This doesn't have api.tx().contracts(). 

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you're right, I missed the updated versions. You should instead use `polkadot::tx().contracts().call(data)`.

Comment: Sorry for the repeated question. But I'm still stuck in there. When I use an updated subxt, ["no method named contracts found for struct polkadot::TransactionApi in the current scope"] Below is my code.

`let call_tx = polkadot::tx().contracts().call(AccountId32::from_string(contract).into(), 0, 20_000_000_000, None, call_data, );`
where `pub mod polkadot{} is from artifacts/polakdot_metadata.scale`

Comment: Are you running a `substrate-contracts-node`? Make sure you run it and not `node-template`.

Comment: Yes, I'm running that. Hmm. I think I need to look into it more. Anyway, your answer helped me so much! Thank you:)

Comment: @Lewis can you please post full solution when you have it. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add, one thing you can do is go to https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9944#/explorer and point it at the node you'd like to call contract code on. See what extrinsics you can submit via that UI. If you can't see contract calls there, that'll be why you also can't see them via Subxt. Also, make sure that Subxt is pointed at metadata for the node you want to talk to so that it knows about any contract stuff that might be available :)

Comment: You can check that polkadot_metadata.scale does not include pallet Contracts:
`subxt explore --file artifacts/polakdot_metadata.scale`

To add Contracts to the file you can run:
`subxt metadata --url ws://127.0.0.1:9944 --pallets Contracts,System -f bytes > artifacts/polakdot_metadata.scale`

Don't forget to add all pallets you need, others are missing then.